# What can a familiar actually do?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars

The PHB states: "A familiar can’t attack, but it can take other actions as normal."

What can a familiar do? Can it use a potion of healing on a character? Can it drop caltrops?

Comment: [Related] [Can a Familiar aid a Rogue's Sneak Attack?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58973/can-a-familiar-aid-a-rogues-sneak-attack)

Answer (score 62):

As far as actions in combat are concerned, the quote you've included pretty much sums it up. A familiar can take any action that it is capable of other than the Attack action. This includes the Cast A Spell action, Dash, Disengage, Dodge, Help, Hide, Ready, Search, and Use an Object. Since familiars are monsters, they can also take any non-Attack action included in their statblock. For example, the octopus has an ink cloud ability.

Note that what exactly your familiar is capable of is up to your DM. For example, I would probably allow an intelligent lizard to scatter caltrops. An intelligent seahorse, on the other hand, I can't quite see administering potions. See also [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/12903/15469) 3.5 question for more information.

It's also worth noting that the familiar granted by the Warlock's Pact of the Chain *can* Attack, but it requires you to give up one of your own attacks.

However, I believe you are slightly missing the point of a familiar - just like in previous editions, its primary purpose is utility, not combat. For example, my players have used a raven familiar as a messenger and aerial scout. They have also mapped out an entire cave complex before setting a single foot in it using a lizard familiar. And finally, (I'm actually still slightly annoyed about this), they effectively *skipped* a covert, stealthy adventure through creative use of the lizard.

Comment: It is important to remember that a familiar is usually just a basic animal. Thus it is subject to the food chain. It is not an invincible extention of the player. Roving hawks, bobcats, other lizards, barracuda, etc can be used to curtail familiar movements if the DM wishes so.

Comment: The primary purpose of a familiar might be changing from utility *to* combat with Xanathar’s Guide spell Dragon Breath which allows an owl to breath elemental fire/cold/electricity etc.

Comment: the help action is really powerfull, especially when used by an owl.

Answer (score 16):

The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SA-Compendium.pdf) confirms that familiars can both use the Help action to grant advantage on an attack roll, as well as function as "allies" for the purposes of Sneak Attack:

> **Can the familiar you conjure with the find familiar spell
>   use the Help action to grant you advantage on your attack
>   roll?** A familiar can’t attack, but it can take non-attack
>   actions, including Help. As the text of the Help action indicates
>   (PH, 192), the action doesn’t require you to be able to
>   attack; you simply need to be able to provide some sort of
>   distraction.
>
> **Does the familiar of find familiar count as an ally for the
>   purposes of Sneak Attack?** A familiar is an allied creature.
>   Its proximity to a target can allow you to use the Sneak Attack
>   feature or any other feature that requires the presence
>   of an ally.

Answer (score 13):

A familiar can be a very potent combat ally. If the familiar uses the Help action each round you can get advantage on your first attack roll each round against an enemy.

If you are a rogue, you also effectively get a permanent sneak attack since there is always and ally within 5' of an enemy.

And specific to Warlocks with Pact of the Chain, the familiar's low hit points are mitigated by invisibility (three of the available special familiars can go invisible).

In addition, for spell casters, you can deliver touch based attacks through your familiar while you are out of range.

Comment: This is not true; a familiar cannot help to give advantage on attack rolls. "A character can only provide help if the task is one that he or she could attempt alone." PHB 175

Comment: @Icyfire In the spell description (pg. 240) it says, "A familiar can't attack, but it can take other actions as normal." This includes the Help action. You may be confusing the combat Help action with helping another player with an ability check.

Answer (score 2):

Find familiar PHB p240

> Finally, when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell. Your familiar must be within 100 feet of you, and it must use its reaction to deliver the spell when you cast it. If the spell requires an attack roll, you use your attack modifier for the roll.

So while a normal familiar (i.e. not using the  Warlock's Pact of the Chain feature) cannot use the attack option on it's turn, a spellcaster can use the familiar's *reaction* for that round to attempt to deliver a touch range spell cast on the caster's turn. The familiar attempts to deliver the spell using a touch attack using the caster's attack modifier. As it uses the familiar's *reaction* this touch attack is the *only* thing it can do (no movement, no anything) so it would have to already be within reach of the target on the caster's turn.

Comment: The familiar can do much more than deliver touch attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Something fun you could do with a familiar is cast the second level concentration spell "Dragon's Breath" on it.

"You touch one willing creature and imbue it with the power to spew magical energy from its mouth, provided it has one. Choose acid, cold, fire, lightning, or poison. Until the spell ends, the creature can use an action to exhale energy of the chosen type in a 15-foot cone. Each creature in that area must make a Dexterity saving throw, taking 3d6 damage of the chosen type on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one."

Although the familiar will usually be targeted immediately, it is still such a fun idea to have an owl or other small familiar act as
a tiny dragon for you. Also it is a bonus action to cast, the familiar can "cast" it on itself as a touch spell using it's reaction along with your bonus action, so it could use it as soon as it gets it's turn with it.

Comment: You might want to add that since this is an area-of-effect with a save, it technically does not count as the familiar making an attack.