# Can the help action trigger a Rogue's sneak attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, rogue, sneak-attack, helping

Let's say that I determined the best course of action is using the Help action to give my Rogue buddy an advantage on his attack instead of attacking by myself. Would that attack then gain the sneak attack bonus since he's at attacking at advantage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Familiar aid a Rogue's Sneak Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58973/can-a-familiar-aid-a-rogues-sneak-attack)

Comment: This is a weird case... on the one hand, it seems like a distinct question being slightly more broad, but on the other, the answers clearly overlap

Comment: @Axoren The real question is, would someone looking for an answer to THIS question click on the other question. I'd say no.

Comment: If anything, the other question is a duplicate of this one, as it's a more specific example of this more general question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Sneak Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/rogue#SneakAttack) says:

> Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack **if you have advantage on the attack roll.**

The [Help](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Help) action says:

> If your ally attacks the target before your next turn, **the first attack
>   roll is made with advantage.**

Sneak Attack can be used if the attack roll is made with advantage (or an enemy of the target to be with 5 feet); the Help action gives that advantage, as long as the rogue is the first ally to attack the target (and the advantage isn't canceled out by disadvantage). It's that simple.

Comment: "as long as the rogue is the first ally to attack the target" - why is that? The wording seems to suggest you are aiding a specific ally, not just the next person attacking that target...

Comment: Ah. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128393/do-i-choose-the-target-or-the-ally-for-the-help-action?rq=1 seems to answer my question. Strange that the wording is seemingly different in different places.