# Can a wizard's familiar take an action on its own?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars

The rule I'm used to from previous editions is that a character with a companion such as a familiar must choose whether to use their Move and Action themselves or have their summoned creature use it. From the answer here ([What can a familiar actually do?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/what-can-a-familiar-actually-do-in-5th-edition)) I'm getting the sense that the familiar has an action of its own. Is this the case?

Comment: What previous edition did you play?  familiars are regular creatures everywhere but 4th edition, as far as I can tell.

Comment: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 3.5 and 4th. No Pathfinder, Basic, Expert or OD&D. I was thinking about this in 4e terms, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the *Find Familiar* entry:

> In combat, it rolls its own
>   initiative and acts on its own turn. A familiar can’t attack, but it can take other actions as normal.

A familiar is an independent creature with its own initiative, movement, actions, and so on. So it can take an action, a bonus action, and a reaction. (Assuming it has something to do with them.)