What ways can a pure martial get Find Familiar at level 1?
I want to have a familiar on a character of a class without access to Spellcasting or Pact Magic features, and I want this to occur at level 1.
The way I know how to do it is with a feat that gives access to a level 1 spell, like Ritual Caster, but I don't want the character to be a variant Human; they are too mundane.
Are there ways to get a feat at level 1 without being a human or to obtain a familiar through some other means while still at level 1? (So multiclassing or a subclass that give classes like fighters and rogues spell slots are off the table.)

What do you mean by "a pure martial class"? What class it is? There is no such term in 5e rules.

I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question is about if magic initate or ritual caster can get you a "full featured" familiar. This one is about NOT using a feat, because the asker wants a familiar on level 1 without being a variant human, so they would not have access to those feats. It might be OK to leave it closed for now for clarification what is meant by "pure martial class", but I wouldn't think it should be closed as a dupe.

@NobodytheHobgoblin That question stated a couple of potential options, but is still asking the same general question as this one, with this quote from there: “Aside from multiclassing, what other options are available in 5e for getting a familiar?” So what do you think is the difference between “what other options are available for getting a familiar” and this question asking what ways there are of getting a familiar without using variant human?

@ThomasMarkov I think the difference is "Are there some other ways to get a starting feat or obtain find familiar for a pure martial class at level 1? I'd prefer not to play a variant human if I can avoid it.", i.e. the normal options to get either feat is out of bounds, because (1) level 1 = no multiclass (2) no variant human = no normal level 1 feat. In the other question, you can get the feats without problem, unless I misunderstand it. They even start out with "lets say I am a variant human"

While the titles are similar, the answers for https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107297/i-am-neither-a-wizard-nor-a-warlock-how-can-i-get-a-full-featured-familiar are largely about the functioning of find familiar.
The requirements of being level 1 and not a human, I hope, make this a sufficiently different topic to be explored. Only 2 of the listed options for findinga familiar in that question match the use case here.
This question has also received answers like Kill a Wyrmling Dragon or get a Draconic Gift that are not in the other post.

Thanks for the comment @enkryptor. I've added clarification to the description that a martial class is a class without access to spellcasting or pact magic features.

Does this answer your question? What are the ways that I can access the spell Find Familiar via magic items or feats?

@justhalf That's a useful thread and much closer to what I am looking for. Thank you. It does ask for racial abilities to be ruled out, and I'm more than happy to find a way to do it via a racial feature. In fact, I think the Custom Lineage option mathaddict shared is the route I will take.

Even though this question is slightly different than the mentioned question, all valid answers to this question will be a sub set of all valid answers to the mentioned question. I think that qualifies as a duplicate.

Does this answer your question? I am neither a Wizard, nor a Warlock. How can I get a "full-featured" familiar? I'm perfectly happy to dupe it to both, but this is really just a retread of the same ground already covered.

@ShadowRanger that dupe target won't work. This question explicitely disallows variant humans as a solution, while your dupe target takes it as a prerequisite and specifically asks about it. As such, those two questions are mutually exclusive.

The answer I found most useful and accepted was using Custom Lineage to get a feat at level 1. That answer is not a valid response to either of the proposed duplicate questions.  as they both rule out racial answers. (One is for a character who is already a variant human, and the other says they are too far down the path to change race)
There is overlap, but I am thankful for the answers here as the ones on the other questions did not meet the use case I had.

Custom Lineage gives you a feat at level 1
Source: Tasha's Cauldron of Everything

Instead of choosing one of the game's races for your character at 1st
level, you can use the following traits to represent your character's
lineage, giving you full control over how your character's origin
shaped them:
Creature type. You are a humanoid. You determine your appearance and whether you resemble any of your kin.
Size. You are Small or Medium (your choice).
Speed. Your base walking speed is 30 feet.
Ability Score Increase. One ability score of your choice increases by 2.
Feat. You gain one feat of your choice for which you qualify.
Variable Trait. . You gain one of the following options of your
choice:
Darkvision with a range of 60 feet.
Proficiency in one skill of your choice.
Languages. You can speak, read, and write Common and one other
language that you and your DM agree is appropriate for your character.

Note that Custom Lineage is not human as per the OP's requirement.

Thank you! This fits the bill perfectly. I asked my DM about this, and he is more than happy to let me use Custom Lineage and be a non-human race. It is not as fantastic as killing a wyrmling, but it is more obtainable for my group.

Kill a wyrmling dragon
Fizban's Treasury of Dragons includes the following draconic gift (p. 28):

Draconic Familiar
Draconic Gift, Uncommon
You gain the aid of a draconic familiar, which might be a splinter of the consciousness of a dragon that invested you with power.
You can cast the find familiar spell as a ritual without using any material components. When you cast the spell in this way, your familiar always takes the form of a pseudodragon.

Uncommon draconic gifts can be won from killing a wyrmling dragon. A white dragon wyrmling, for example, is CR2 - a very risky and deadly fight for a level 1 party, due to the breath weapon, but winnable with a bit of luck and preparation. (How you deal with the enraged parents is another story — best leave no tracks and make sure to leave the scene fast and far).
Of course, you then also need to work with your DM and have your DM play along and have this be the transfer of power draconic gift effect. But it's an official rules based way to get this spell on level one for a martial, it is not based on just pandering to the DM for a gratuitous handout - you will have earned it. So, become a dragonslayer.
(Or, as @TreeSpawned points out, the dragon can also bestow this gift to their chosen heir (p. 27) so with DM support, this could be part of your backstory).

That is not an answer I expected, but I love it! Thank you for sharing.

You don't even have to kill a Dragon to get a Draconic Gift. Page 27 states a Dragon can also bestow such gifts to their "chosen heir".

@TreeSpawned Good point, I added a note on it.

Obtain a Ring of Spell Storing
And a friendly caster who knows Find Familiar
The Ring of Spell Storing allows another caster to load up the item with spells up to 5th level, which includes Find Familiar. The person attuned to the ring (you in this case) can then cast the spell, with the effects acting with you as the caster - meaning you gain control of the familiar.
You'll need someone who knows the spell to cast it into the ring for you at least once initially, and if your familiar later dies (or you want to change its form) you'll need a new copy of the spell loaded. The ring can store up to 5 spell levels, so up to 5 castings of Find Familiar 'banked' at a time. If you don't have a party member with the spell, your DM could allow a friendly NPC to load up your ring on occasion.
The ring is a Rare item, and so usually not something that you'd find at 1st level. However, working with your DM you could, for example, come to an arrangement where the item is specifically only used for Find Familiar, making it less of a balance issue for those early levels.

This is a good option later game to give all the party familiars.

In addition to the other answers provided, you could use a Spellwrought Tattoo (Common) from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything. This is of course dependant on if your DM allows you to start with a magic item of common rarity. If they do, they could just as easily just allow you to start with it already cast.
The Spellwrought Tattoo lets you cast the spell only once, but so long as your familiar doesn't die, you presumably only need to cast it once and can still summon/dismiss it at your will. You won't be able to change its form without recasting the spell however.

Spellwrought Tattoo
Source: Tasha's Cauldron of Everything
Wondrous item (tattoo), rarity varies
Produced by a special needle, this magic tattoo contains a single
spell of up to 5th level, wrought on your skin by a magic needle. To
use the tattoo, you must hold the needle against your skin and speak
the command word. The needle turns into ink that becomes the tattoo,
which appears on the skin in whatever design you like. Once the tattoo
is there, you can cast its spell, requiring no material components.
The tattoo glows faintly while you cast the spell and for the spell's
duration. Once the spell ends, the tattoo vanishes from your skin.
The level of the spell in the tattoo determines the spell's saving
throw DC, attack bonus, spellcasting ability modifier, and the
tattoo's rarity, as shown in the Spellwrought Tattoo table.


This is an excellent idea. We do get to start with some magic items, so I’ll see if this could be one.

If you choose a race with racial casting you can pick up a Strixhaven Primer.
It allows you to cast one level one spell once for free after a long rest, no spell slot required. The choice of school dictates what classes spell list you have access to; for example Witherbloom can choose Druid or Wizard spells. The attunement requirement is ‘Spellcaster’ so play a Drow, Elf, maybe even a Forest Gnome and make your familiar.
(You can also change the spell each day while keeping your familiar, for something useful on the fly, but I understand keeping Find Familiar as an option in case you lose your buddy.)

A non-custom lineage option would be either rewarded or ruined backgrounds, which can grant the magic initiate feat.
Gold buy route could give you enough to buy a scroll spell wrought tattoo of find familiar as well

Thanks, I didn't realize Wotc had introduced background options that grant feats. One note, I see http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/background:rewarded offers it, but http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/background:ruined does not (Only Alert, Skilled, or Tough)

@JohnRichardsII If they stick to what they did in the Playtest Material, then in the new PHB coming out in September 2024, every background will grant a feat.
