# Can Familiars read and use spell scrolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, familiars

I'm playing an Artificer/Rogue ([2019 version on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#Archivist), going for Archivist but I took magic initiate and got Find Familiar) and I want to get a little more support ability by using spell scrolls, Cure Wounds, Earth Bind, Fog Cloud, Etc. But I'm wondering if my Familiar can use those scrolls. Scrolls must be read in order to be cast, but does that mean out loud or does one simply need to understand the writing to cast the spell? What if my Familiar can read and speak, but isn't a spell caster of any kind?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can a Familiar Actually do?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/what-can-a-familiar-actually-do)

Comment: [Obligatory oots](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots1020.html)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## No, a familiar conjured from Find Familiar cannot decipher or cast any spell scroll.

From [Spell Scroll](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll):

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll and cast its spell without providing any material components. Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible.

So, in your scenario with [*Find Familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar), there is no familiar you can summon that can decipher any spell scrolls.

I believe this counts for all of the possible familiars, as none I can find have spell casting abilities.

Comment: Even if one summons a familiar with spell casting abilities, it wouldn't have the **spell** on its **class' spell list** as it would lack a **class**. (Assuming it would have the *Innate Spellcasting* on its monster entry). I don't think the game would ever make a creature with the *Spellcasting* special ability a familiar. Only the latter could use a scroll: `The monster is considered a member of that class when attuning to or using a magic item that requires membership in the class or access to its spell list.`