# What happens to a familiar if the wizard is unconscious?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, unconscious

Reading over the PHB spell entry for familiars, I don't see anything about what happens to the familiar if its "owner" dies or is unconscious. I'm going to assume if the owner dies, the familiar disappears, but what if the owner is merely knocked out?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Nothing.

There is no current rule that spell effects end when a caster is unconscious or dies *unless* they are specifically concentration spells.

Thus, since Find Familiar is not a concentration spell, it's perfectly reasonable to assume that the familiar stays and is unaffected by the fact that his wizard is unconscious (or dead).

And in fact, the duration of the Find Familiar spell is "instantaneous" meaning that once the familiar is created, it's there, and there is no continuing effect of the spell. It can't even be dispelled.

It's important to note that if your DM wants to rule that *current* spell effects (like say, spiritual weapon), end when you go unconscious, it would *not* affect a spell like Find Familiar since again, the duration of that spell is instantaneous.

Comment: I wonder if a familiar could be trained by the owner to use a healing potion on its unconscious owner?

Comment: @RobertF depending on the type of familiar, it's a possibility, You'd have to check the spell to see how much leeway they have re: autonomous action.

Comment: @RobertF this was addressed in two locations: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/what-can-a-familiar-actually-do-in-5th-edition?rq=1

http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12903/can-a-cat-familiar-open-a-potion-bottle-by-itself?rq=1

Comment: @Dan That second link is for a different game though.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, and some of the answers are specific to 3.5e. But the accepted answer isn't, and the link was provided as additional information, not an answer to a real, posted question.

Comment: From my interpretation of what's stated, it doesn't specifically state that it can't be trained to do actions and from what it says, it seems to imply autonomous actions are allowed...the only 'issue' would be 'could' the familiar manipulate the potion bottle -- which could be addressed by a smart Wizard, creating a familiar friendly magic item. @RobertF

Answer (score 0):

Technically, 
Nothing.
(Ok, maybe, if the Wizard dies, then, possibly it 'disappears' from the story...or self-suicides)

Ok..reading the 5e rules,, it's still a 'spirit' forced into a shape of a common animal...which, doesn't necessarily invalidate the point that it can be trained (without necessarily having to take Animal Training...and some bonus could be given due to the fact that you have Telepathic communication)

If the Wizard is unconscious, the familiar would act as an independent creature -- and, according to it's nature/training (e.g. a dog might stay and protect him/her, while a cat might slink away with an eye toward an ambush, or a rat might scurry away)[with the only 5e addition being, it can't take an Attack Action] -- it doesn't proscribe it from executing a Trained action (e.g. The question of could a cat familiar drink a potion).  A smart Wizard might create a familiar-triggered magic item that a familiar could use...

The way I've always seen it is a familiar is a permanent summoned creature who is common to your locale who matches your alignment (i.e. it can't be dispelled or banished -- except in 5e it's also essentially immortal)