# What happens to a Wizard's Transmuter Stone when she dies?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, character-death

Unfortunately, last monday night our transmuter wizardess met her early (only 160!) demise at the hands (claws) of some elf-hungry trolls.

Her transmuter stone was not on her, because another character borrowed it to get +10 movement and carry an urgent message to the king.

Now, we had to stop the session because there is a time-rift. Either the stone keeps working after her death, or it stops.

If the stone keeps working the runner will press on to the king's location. But if the stone stopped working, the runner will go back to find the wizardess' corpse or get in touch with [her familiar](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/53278/11402) and then find the corpse. And the runner has enough arcana to know that she died (there is the fact that she could've made another stone, but not eight hours had passed).

> (...) you can spend 8 hours creating a
>   transmuter's stone (...) If you create a new transmuter's stone, the previous
>   one ceases to function.

So, after that not-so-quick exposition, once a transmuter wizard soul departs the body, do the transmuter stone keep working?

---

Regarding the golden rule, I'm the DM of the game, and I have no idea on how to rule the issue. So I can't really ask the DM.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**The stone keeps working.**

Jeremy Crawford has weighed in on this over on [Sage Advice](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/11/12/if-a-transmutation-wizard-dies-does-their-transmuters-stone-lose-its-effects/):

> **Q:** if a transmutation wizard dies, does their transmuter's stone lose its effects?
>
> **A:** The transmuter's stone doesn't lose its magic if the transmuter dies. The text would say if it did.

Comment: google failed me. Now to find a cliff and jump over.

Comment: Note that Crawford's tweets are not "Sage Advice"; that's just the name of a third-party site that compiles designer tweets. Also, since [Crawford's tweets are no longer official rulings as of January 2019](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/with-the-2019-sage-advice-compendium-release-are-jeremy-crawfords-tweets-consi), you might want to expand this answer to support it by pointing to the rules (and the fact that, as Crawford says, the feature indeed doesn't say the stone loses its magic if the wizard dies).

Comment: I'd argue it feels both more balanced and more beneficial for the campaign to overrule that advice.